# Set display name to value of another property - MVC3 Data Annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

Is it possible to set the DisplayName Data Attribute to the value of another property in a viewmodel?

```
public class FieldModel
{
    public string DisplayText { get; set; }
    public bool Mandatory { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public string HelpText { get; set; }

    [DisplayName(this.DisplayText)]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, but you can derive from DisplayNameAttribute and override `DisplayNameValue { get; }` to fetch the value from your class instead.

(apologies, don't have time to write a code sample just now)

It looks like MVC will use DisplayAttribute.GetName() in preference to DisplayNameAttribute but that's a sealed class.

Comment: interesting. how do you get an instance reference to the attributed parent class of the property?

Comment: You're right: that isn't possible after all. I think back then I thought that you'd be able to access attributes with context of what they are attached to, and I'm still a bit surprised there's no built-in way to do that.